# How to make custom datatypes in php?

Tags: php, custom-data-type

I know in other languages how to make a new custom datatype, but how do I do this in PHP? Sometimes I need something that doesn't fit in the categories of a String, Integer, Float, Bool, Array, Object, Null, or Resource (often with a *very* different set of standard interactions and operators). How do I do this?

Comment: Can you give an example?  What about defining a new class and then you can use the instanceof comparison operator?

Comment: For a true data type, you can't unless you wanted to add it to the C source. However, you can fake many of the interactions with the built in magic methods or interfaces.

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn 
So you'd have to alter in C and rebuilt, and you're running a custom version of PHP from there on out? Okay, good to know. I was hoping it'd be easier than that.

Comment: @Devon 
Using stuff as its own raw datatype allows for faster operations than using classes. Not normally a big issue, but for doing something like building a server for protein folder with a web-run interface, can make a huge difference. (Basically having a molecule datatype with chemistry-based operators. Trying to make as a class can make some very bulky instantiations and complicated calls.)

Comment: If you were trying to do something for speed like protein folding, I would never suggest doing it in php. Instead I would suggest making something to run on the server in C/C++ and then you can use php to run the program, interface with it, make system calls and check logs to get updates about the status. Super complicated an highly parallel processes will not benefit much from a scripting language like php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to add custom datatypes to PHP, I could not find any way or documentation saying you could, but I think you can always modify the PHP Core in order to achieve that (Which I would not recommend to do if you dont know what you are doing).

My suggestion is to create classes, that way you can typehint a variable by its classname.

Comment: As far as editing the PHP core, what would you suggest as being the best part of the code to look at (or resource) to plan such a thing?

Comment: I would not know how to even start. I have never done this before so I am not the right person to give you directions in this matter. Sorry I cant help more.

Answer (score 1):

With PHP 8 you can kinda emulate it with classes, by receiving custom value in some custom class form, processing or rejecting it accordignly and storing it in that object:

```php
class Request {
    // logic of receiving / processing / storing custom data type
}

// function's parameter has to be type of Request
function test(Request $x) {

}

test(new Request);
```